# cant turn on developer mode on Lenovo a916

Tags: android

I am trying to run my android studio project on Levono a916 device. I cant figure out how to turn on the developer mode. I can not find System information inside about phone nor anything related to developer mode. The os on it is 4.4

Comment: Since this question is off-topic as it does not pertain to programming, it belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings-> About -> Software Information and tap about 7-9 times -> Build Number

Comment: When I Go Settings->About phone-> I don't see Software Information

Comment: Search for build number in your settings menu